# jQuery UI Icons trouble - how do I get just the image displayed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, icons

Using jQuery UI icons I just want to display the icon in line with the rest ("just display the icon, no line breaks etc.). Basically I want to get a row of clickable images, while I am using [jQuery UI themes for my page](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/08/style-html-table-using-jquery-ui-and.html).

Here some things I have tried:

```
1: <div style="display:inline-block;width:20px;height:20px" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"/>
2: <input type="image" onclick=".." class="ui-icon ui-icon-search" alt="Look up" title="Look up (to address)" value="Reverse Lookup" />
```

1: completely messing up the layout.
2: gives my an extra line break around the image

-- as request wider context --

```
 <tr class="ui-widget-content">
   <td>...</td>
   <td>
      <input name="xy" id="xy" type="text" size="5" />
      <input name="xz" id="xz" type="text" size="5" />
      <input type="image" onclick="...;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-search" alt="Look up" title="Look up (to address)" value="Reverse Lookup" />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

-- span --

Using `span` leads to the same as above, icon is displayed but in its own line.

```
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-n"></span>
```

[image]

Comment: Using icons where exactly? In what context?

Comment: You can't use a sprite image like a normal image, if you want to show a UI icon inline try applying it to a span (inline element) tag.  e.g.  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-n"></span>

Comment: Yep, but what was basically missing was the inline-block as in the answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the key is to make the icon containers `display: inline-block`.

```
<div style="display: inline-block" class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-lightbulb"></span>
</div>
```

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/2U5TN/1/.

Also, you may find this page useful: http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/static/icons.html. It displays all possible icons you can use with jQuery UI CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Use the toolbar Example on the Jquery UI site http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#toolbar

Setting text to false will just show the icon:

```
$( "#beginning" ).button({
            text: false,
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-seek-start"
            }
        });
```

It also appears they use the text value to keep track of the state of the button. Check the play/pause and stop buttons in the example.

Comment: From the above link I came also across http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/ which is a nice intro. Thanks for pointing in that direction.